# Google Analytics - segment metrics into ranges

Tags: google-analytics

Within GA, is it possible to segment metrics into ranges?

For example -

- Average Page load time > 2s
- Average Page load time 2 - 4s
- Average Page load time < 4s

Or is this only doable with further processing in excel/sheets?

**Edit -**

Specifically, I am looking to build a report that looks at average load time and the effects on conversion, bounce rate, AOV, etc. for the site and for specific pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.  The longer answer is that you could try the following two things:

1. Filter the report as this will allow you to define ranges:
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT213.png)
2. Implement your own user timing logic and set a time-format custom metric

Just keep in mind that if you did go for #2 that you'd be setting a hit-scope custom metric so when you come to use it in a segment you'll be forced to look at sessions/users who had a page load time within a session or group of sessions with your given thresholds.

If you had a specific business question in mind it may be more appropriate for me to provide a solution to that as it may be different...

Comment: Thanks Steve. I edited my question above to add the business question behind my technical question. Thanks!